# how to show Google maps called by Intent.ACTION_VIEW in my UI?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

I am good at displaying Google Maps I want to show in my app, according to the instruction of the new Google Maps APIs version 2.

But I got a question : As you know, we can show easily Google Map using Intent.ACTION_VIEW. In this case, we can see just only the screen of the defaulted Google Maps. I would like to show this map(called by intent.ACTION_VIEW) in my XML layout or layout class. Namely, I want to insert this map(called by intent.ACTION_VIEW) within my customized layout(UI). AFAIK, this UI is likely to be .java.

Please let me know HOW TO. It's not possible?

Answer (score 1):

> It's not possible?

You cannot embed the UI of another app in your own. You are welcome to use the Maps V1 or Maps V2 APIs to add Google Maps to your app, but you cannot otherwise embed the actual Maps *app* into your UI.

Comment: Thanks. you say, Google Maps called by the Intent is an  actual Maps app. Is it neither an Activity? nor an API?. (AFAIK, Google Maps called by the Intent is not an API(or Activity), but a complete app embedded in the Handset.)

Comment: @BBonDoo: The Maps application contains several activities. It is not an API.

Comment: OK. I see. Thanks a lot. I have a reason why I have interested in the Google Maps invoked by Intent. As you know, one is that it is very simple and easy to get a map int an app, another is that it don't need the permission and API key, and the last is that it is to be able to show the maps contents(including polylines or -gons, markers pre-made in PC) more esaier than with Google Maps APIs.

Answer (score 1):

The Intent.ACTION_VIEW is used to launch another app. This means, you will leave your app, and google maps app will be opened.

If you want to add your own UI, you have to use a MapView inside your own app.
[Developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/)

Comment: @Entreco..Thanks..I do know MapView or Mapfragment very well. I just have thought if I can bring the google Maps(called by Intent) to my customized UI (in layout source code).